# Where are tree hashes stored in git?

Tags: git, hash

I am following this tutorial (https://jwiegley.github.io/git-from-the-bottom-up/1-Repository/3-blobs-are-stored-in-trees.html) to learn about git architecture.

The command

```
$ git cat-file commit HEAD
```

gives me the hash for the tree referenced by HEAD, "0563f77d884e4f79ce95117e2d686d7d6e282887".  Now, I try to find this hash in `.git`:

```
$ find .git/ | xargs grep "0563f77"
```

Why does nothing come up?  Is this hash not stored anywhere?

Comment: It worked for the commit hash, returned by `$ git rev-parse HEAD`.  This hash is stored in `.git/refs/heads/master`, `.git/logs/refs/heads/master`, and `.git/logs/HEAD`.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968856/what-is-the-file-format-of-a-git-commit-object-data-structure and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790681/what-is-the-internal-format-of-a-git-tree-object for an overview of the underlying data structures.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're mixing together several concepts here:

- Git's internal object *names* (SHA-1 hashes) are unique to (and are entirely dictated by, and hence in a philosophical sense *are*) the contents of the object.  More correctly, they are the SHA-1 hash of the object's type-name taken as a string (`commit`, `blob`, `tree`, or `tag`), followed by a space and then a decimalized representation of the length of the object in bytes, followed by a NUL or zero byte, followed by the raw data of the underlying object.

  Note that if you hash the same object twice, you get the same hash both times.  Thus, if a file named `README.txt` has some text in it, and then you copy that file to `read-me-too.txt` and hash *that* file, you get the same hash again.  This is because the *name* of the file is not part of the input to the hash computation, only the *type* (in this case `blob`), the blank, the size, the zero-byte, and the contents.

  If the two files contain just one line reading `hello` (plus a newline, for six bytes total), the input to the hash function is `blob 6\0hello\n` (where `\0` and `\n` stand for the zero-byte and the newline).   In fact, the hash of these two files is `ce013625030ba8dba906f756967f9e9ca394464a`.  (I used `git hash-object` to find this value, although any SHA-1 code will do the trick: you can find this with a few lines of Python or Ruby code, or a fair number of lines of C code, for instance.  Hashing trees is [trickier](https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/githash.py).)

  The object ID `ce013625030ba8dba906f756967f9e9ca394464a` represents a file containing the word `hello` followed by a newline.<sup>1</sup>  (If we know what data a file contains, we can hash the data and find the Git object ID.  Normally we go the other way: we start from a valid Git object ID, and we retrieve the data from the repository.  But when we `git add` a file, we go this way, turning the data into a hash and storing it as a Git object, if it is not already in the repository.  If it *is* already in, we're all good: we just use the same hash again.)
- The object itself—the object's data—is stored somewhere in the Git repository.

  The location you found, where object `0563f77d884e4f79ce95117e2d686d7d6e282887` is in a directory named `05` with a file whose name starts with `63f77` and continues on with the rest of the hash, is where Git currently keeps what it calls *loose objects*.  However, Git also *packs* objects into what it calls *pack files*.

  The format of pack files is rather complicated, and would take too long to go into here.  We can, however, say that a single pack file can store tens of thousands of objects.  (Pack file formats have been revised several times to improve performance and individual object accessibility.)
- We need a method to convert from *human-readable* names, like branch names, to Git hashes.  This is what you found in the search you noted in a comment:

  > It worked for the commit hash, returned by `$ git rev-parse HEAD`. This hash is stored in `.git/refs/heads/master` [and two reflogs]

  Git's design offers two particularly well-distinguished external name forms, specifically *branch names* and *tag names*, with which we can remember particular commit hashes.  Git's general term for this is *references*.  Git's *remote-tracking branches* are references as well, stored under `refs/remotes/`.  Besides these branch and tag names, you are likely to encounter *notes* and "the stash" (`git stash`): these also use references, specifically those in `refs/notes/` and the (single) name `refs/stash` respectively.

  As with objects, reference values are stored somewhere in the Git repository, but you are not promised that they remain in individual files.  As of today (Git version 2.9) they are always in either individual files like the one you found, or in a single special file named `packed-refs` (or occasionally in both: in this case the individual file has the correct value, if the two disagree).

A branch name is just a reference that starts with `refs/heads/`<sup>2</sup>.  A tag is a name that starts with `refs/tags/`<sup>3</sup>.  Either one will let you find the SHA-1 hash of a commit.  The key difference between the two is that a branch name is *expected* to change over time, pointing to the newest commit on the branch; but a tag name should point to the *same* commit forever.

In fact, not only is a branch name expected to change, Git will *automatically* change it *for you*.  In particular, if `git status` says that you are `on branch master`, and you make a *new* commit, Git will change `refs/heads/master` to point to the new commit.  Git also makes the new commit have, as its parent commit ID, the commit `master` pointed to just before you made the new commit.  This is how a branch grows: the reference always points to the tip-most commit, by definition.  That tip-most commit points, through its parent ID, to an earlier commit, which points further back in history, and so on.  (And if a commit is a *merge commit*, it has two, or maybe even three or more, parent IDs instead of just one.)

What this means is that **a key place you will find these Git object IDs is inside other Git objects**.

This is what you see when you pretty-print a commit (with `git cat-file -p HEAD` or `git cat-file commit HEAD`, both of which do the same thing): you view the contents of the tip commit of the current branch, and you see `tree <ugly-sha-1>`.  So the tree ID is stored *in the commit*.  If the commit is itself in a loose object, however, and you bring up `.git/objects/05/...` in a file editor or viewer, you won't see that hash, or even the word `tree`.  This is because the repository data is *compressed* (specifically, with [`zlib`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib); objects stored in pack files are compressed differently, using a modified version of [`xdelta`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdelta), and then also zlib-deflated).  This is also why you can and should use something like `git cat-file` to view the object's contents: that insulates you from the location and format details.  All you need is the object's ID; `git cat-file` will find and decompress the object.

Tree objects themselves contain additional Git object IDs, as you can see by using `git cat-file -p` on a tree:

```
$ git cat-file -p 'HEAD^{tree}'
[snip]
100644 blob cb2ca2bb2e86aa4a4c3c9b08490c72b04a1778d3    rfuncs.h
040000 tree 05006c6f2e6119fede241cf6ec845291a5be665e    sbuf
[snip more]
```

Thus, one particular Git blob object (`cb2ca2b...`) and one additional Git tree object (`05006c6...`) have their Git-object-names saved away inside the tree associated with the `HEAD` commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>The [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) tells us that if we hash enough different objects, we will get `ce013625030ba8dba906f756967f9e9ca394464a` for at least two *different* files.  On that day, Git breaks. :-)  It takes a huge number of inputs to get a hash collision, though.  Probability mathematics suggests that you will lose data on thousands of disk drives long before you get a Git hash collision, even if you have billions of files.  In fact, it takes about 1.71 quadrillion files to raise the probability of a hash collision to one in 10<sup>-18</sup>, which is a typical quoted error rate for enterprise-grade storage media.

Of course, these assume random chance inputs, rather than maliciously constructed files using cryptography theory to attempt to break Git.

<sup>2</sup>It's no coincidence that you found the file `master` inside `refs/heads`.  Someday, though, Git may no longer store names in flat files since this imposes file-system restrictions on branch naming: in particular it makes it impossible to have both a branch named `x` and a branch named `x/y`.  Note that when the references are in `.git/packed-refs`, it *is* possible to have both `x` and `x/y`, at least in an information-theoretic sense.  It's merely an annoying file system restriction that you cannot have a file named `x` *and* a directory also named `x` containing a file named `y`.  (There's no particularly good reason for this file system restriction either, except that POSIX requires it.)

<sup>3</sup>If a tag is an annotated tag, it refers to a Git object of type "tag", which then points to the next object.  In fact, this is the definition of an annotated tag name: it's a name in `refs/tags/` that points to an annotated tag object.  The tag object usually points directly to a commit, although you can tag a tag object, instead of tagging a commit directly, and then have to peel both tag layers off to get to the underlying commit.

Git will let you point a tag (lightweight *or* annotated) to any Git object, but will normally only let you point a branch name to a commit object.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  In addition to answering the question I asked, this answered a lot of other questions I had but didn't ask (for example, what was in the loose object files).

Answer (score 4):

The hash is not coming up in a grep because the first two digits of it are the title of a directory:

```
.git/objects/05/63f77d884e4f79ce95117e2d686d7d6e282887
```

The way that git stores information in `.git/objects` is discussed here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
git log --pretty=format:'%T %s'
```

Comment: This just gives me the beginning of the commit hash, not the tree hash.