# Are the github streaks gone?

Tags: github

I noticed that nobody on GitHub has a streak anymore. This does not only happen to me, also to other people's accounts.

[image]

Can I enable it somehow again?

Comment: https://github.com/Naramsim/GithubOriginalStreak

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, streaks are gone.

This was announced on github's blog : [More contributions on your profile](https://github.com/blog/2173-more-contributions-on-your-profile).

Personnaly, I don't think it's a big loss as it was quite easy to fool : [Who is the user with the longest streak on GitHub? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27742165/2003537).